# Not able to create Autoincrement primary key field in ms-access using java

Tags: java, ms-access-2007, ucanaccess

I need to create a table with a autoincrement primary key column> i tried with the following code but it throws error .

**My code:**

```
     CreateTableAccess.CreateAccessTable("CREATE TABLE D_Centre\n"
            + "(\n"
            + "    SlNo AUTOINCREMENT,\n"
            + "    CentreID VARCHAR,\n"
            + "    CentreName VARCHAR,\n"
            + "    [Createddate] DateTime,  \n"
            + "    CreatedBy VARCHAR, \n"
            + "    [Updateddate] DateTime\n"
           + ")", "D_Centre");


    public static void CreateAccessTable(String sqlscript, String tablename )
{
    String dbFileSpec = DataEntryScreen.homedirectory+"/"+"Dataentry.accdb";
    Connection conn = null ;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFileSpec);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateTableAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        DatabaseMetaData dmd = null;
    try {
        dmd = conn.getMetaData();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateTableAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
            ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = dmd.getTables(null, null, tablename , new String[]{"TABLE"});
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateTableAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        // }
        {
        try {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Table ["+tablename+"] already exists.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Table ["+tablename+"] does not exist.");
                Statement s = conn.createStatement();
                  s.executeUpdate(sqlscript);
                System.out.println("Table ["+tablename+"] created.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateTableAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.err.println("Error in table creation  --> "+ex.toString());
        }
        try {
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateTableAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateTableAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}
}
```

**Error:** 
Nov 04, 2014 3:39:28 PM org.DataEntryApplication.view.CreateTableAccess CreateAccessTable
SEVERE: null
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: type not found or user lacks privilege: AUTOINCREMENT
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:164)
    at org.DataEntryApplication.view.CreateTableAccess.CreateAccessTable(CreateTableAccess.java:53)
    at org.DataEntryApplication.view.AccessProcess.accessProcess(AccessProcess.java:40)
    at org.DataEntryApplication.view.DataEntryScreen.addComponentsToPane(DataEntryScreen.java:188)
    at org.DataEntryApplication.view.DataEntryScreen.createAndShowGUI(DataEntryScreen.java:1092)
    at org.DataEntryApplication.view.Login$7.actionPerformed(Login.java:277)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: type not found or user lacks privilege: AUTOINCREMENT
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.addDDLCommand(AbstractExecute.java:105)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:127)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.execute(ExecuteUpdate.java:56)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:162)
    ... 41 more

Error in table creation  --> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: type not found or user lacks privilege: AUTOINCREMENT

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you are using the latest version of UCanAccess, available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/latest/download?source=files).

I just tried the following with UCanAccess 2.0.9.1 and it worked fine for me.

```java
s.executeUpdate(
        "CREATE TABLE D_Centre (" +
                "slNo AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "CentreID VARCHAR(100) " +
            ")");
```

**Edit re: comment**

UCanAccess 2.0.9.1 (and later) does support DEFAULT values for columns, too. I just tested this and it worked:

```
s.executeUpdate(
        "CREATE TABLE D_Centre (" +
                "slNo AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "Centre VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'foo' " +
            ")");
```

Comment: Similarly when am adding default value to a column as s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE D_Centre (slNo AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Centre VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'Chennai')");. It is not creating table rather it throws same error as above

Comment: @Dhinakar I dunno, it works for me (see my updated answer). You *do* have the latest version of UCanAccess (currently 2.0.9.2), right?